# No loss of generality

Tags: model, parameterization

Let
$$
\underset{n \times n}{\Sigma_t} = \underset{n \times m}{A} \underset{m \times m}{\Sigma_t^f} \underset{m \times n}{A'}, \qquad m <n.
$$
In this model $A$ is the parameter matrix. The authors state that "there is no loss of generality in assuming $A$ satisfies the condition $A' A=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what that means or where I can find info on this statement of no loss of generality?

Comment: No loss of generality simply means that the simplifying conditions doesn't affect the result.

Comment: No specific answer to this question is possible unless you also indicate the context: exactly what are the authors attempting to conclude about $\Sigma_t$?